# ValueError: Worksheet index 0 is invalid, 0 worksheets found.Cannot open xlsx with pandas in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

Could someone help me figure out why my files dont open.

```
import pandas as pd
file = "C://Dev//20211103_logfile Box 2.8.xlsx"
temp=pd.read_excel(file)
```

Here is the full error!

```
PS C:\Dev> & C:/Users/keyur/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Dev/test_excel.py      
C:\Users\keyur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\workbook.py:88: 
UserWarning: File contains an invalid specification for 20211103_logfile. This will be removed
  warn(msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Dev\test_excel.py", line 6, in <module>
    temp=pd.read_excel(file)
  File "C:\Users\keyur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\keyur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 372, in read_excel
    data = io.parse(
  File "C:\Users\keyur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1272, in parse
    return self._reader.parse(
  File "C:\Users\keyur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 537, in parse
    sheet = self.get_sheet_by_index(asheetname)
  File "C:\Users\keyur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 546, in get_sheet_by_index
    self.raise_if_bad_sheet_by_index(index)
  File "C:\Users\keyur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 468, in raise_if_bad_sheet_by_index
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Worksheet index 0 is invalid, 0 worksheets found
PS C:\Dev>
```

Comment: What happens is your filename does not include the '.' in the file prefix? eg `"C://Dev//20211103_logfile Box 2_8.xlsx"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are problem with your excel,
try make a new excel and copy pase all data ,then try again ,this method works for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).